# Getting error after using order place after event in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, area

I used below event for order save after Observer. This is my events.xml

```
  <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="sales_order_save_after" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\Ordersave" />
</event>
```

Here is my Observer code

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;
class Ordersave implements ObserverInterface { 
    private $logger;
    private $state;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,       
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {         
    $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->logger = $logger;        
    $this->_state = $state;
  }
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer) { 
      $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
    try{
        $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
        ....
        .... 
        custom code    
     }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->info(' --Exception--  '.$e->getMessage());
     }
    }
}
```

Event is triggering and i can place order with my custom code written inside try block but after order placed i am getting like

```
   There has been an error processing your request
Error log record number: Some number
```

Inside that record i am getting below error.

```
  Area code is not set "1":"  vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Page\/Config.php
```

What is issue in my code please someone suggest me

Comment: Why you use $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);?

Comment: Because it was throwing error after placing order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using the event

```
sales_order_save_commit_after
```

Try below code

```
$orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getEntityId();
```

Comment: Can you please update me how to get order id inside observer?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$observer->getObject()->getId()` for get orderId

Comment: I am getting order id, that is not my error

Comment: Where is  events.xml file? (path)

Comment: its inside etc folder of module

Comment: Magento uses areas to efficiently make web service calls, loading only the dependent code for that area. Examples of areas include the storefront (frontend), Magento Admin (adminhtml, the administration interface), and the WebAPI framework (webapi_rest).
Trying with move events.xml to frontend

Comment: so i need to move events.xml to frontend folder?

Comment: Yes, move it to etc/frontend folder

Comment: Yes, i moved and checked, same again

Comment: Param of execute function is EventObserver (Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)?

Answer (score 0):

Change following code ;

```
 $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
```

to

```
 $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
```

and it should work.

**EDIT :**

Replace this code in your constructor

```
$this->_state = $state;
```

to

```
   $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
```

and remove

```
$this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
```

Comment: After using this code, i am getting error like "Area code already set".

Comment: Then you should remove the code altogether

Comment: Yes Once i removed and checked, i am getting error like "Area code is not set "1" if i add getting "Area code already set" error

Comment: You should set this in the contructor of the class itself, like here - https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-fixing-area-code-not-set-exceptions/

Comment: can you please update me as per my code, the link have different code and it is incomplete

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: events.xml should be inside frontend folder or it can be inside etc only?

Comment: depends on the event.. did it work?

Comment: No, after using that code i am getting "Area code is already set" error in report file

Comment: if your obsever is triggering than events.xml is placed in right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82286/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-vivek-kumar).

Comment: did you remove the code , I have asked to remove

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following code in your observer:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Ordersave implements ObserverInterface { 
    private $logger;
    private $state;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,       
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {         
    $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->logger = $logger;        
    $this->_state = $state;
  }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        try{
            $order_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
            $this->logger->info(' --Exception--  '.$order_id);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info(' --Exception--  '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And change the name of observer to something else.